# active record in codeigniter automatically adds quotes around each where clause comma separared value

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, select, activerecord

I am passing the comma separated values to use in WHERE IN Query clause as

```
$sql = '
            MAX(CASE WHEN rt.machine_name = "new" THEN rt.request_status_count ELSE "0" END) AS "new",
            MAX(CASE WHEN rt.machine_name = "open" THEN rt.request_status_count ELSE "0" END) AS "open",
            MAX(CASE WHEN rt.machine_name = "waiting" THEN rt.request_status_count ELSE "0" END) AS "waiting",
            MAX(CASE WHEN rt.machine_name = "closed" THEN rt.request_status_count ELSE "0" END) AS "closed"
            FROM 
            (SELECT COUNT(r.id) AS request_status_count, rs.name AS status, rs.machine_name AS machine_name
            FROM '. $this->_table . ' r INNER JOIN request_status AS rs ON r.request_status_id = rs.id INNER JOIN organizations AS o ON r.organization_id = o.id '. $where_string .' GROUP BY r.request_status_id) AS rt';

        $this->db->select($sql);
```

The $where_string is passed as

```
$security_clause_string = 'WHERE r.location_id IN ("' . $this->session->userdata('str_user_locations').'")';
```

Where is str_user_locations = 1,2,4

The output of this query is

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '` GROUP BY r.request_status_id) AS rt' at line 4

SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN rt.machine_name = "new" THEN rt.request_status_count ELSE "0" END) AS "new", MAX(CASE WHEN rt.machine_name = "open" THEN rt.request_status_count ELSE "0" END) AS "open", MAX(CASE WHEN rt.machine_name = "waiting" THEN rt.request_status_count ELSE "0" END) AS "waiting", MAX(CASE WHEN rt.machine_name = "closed" THEN rt.request_status_count ELSE "0" END) AS "closed" FROM (SELECT COUNT(r.id) AS request_status_count, `rs`.`name` AS status, `rs`.`machine_name` AS machine_name FROM requests r INNER JOIN request_status AS rs ON r.request_status_id = rs.id INNER JOIN organizations AS o ON r.organization_id = o.id WHERE r.location_id IN ("1, `2`, `3")` GROUP BY r.request_status_id) AS rt
```

Comment: If `location_id` is int you may do as `WHERE r.location_id IN (' . $this->session->userdata('str_user_locations').')'`

Comment: location_id will be multiple ID's so I am passing as 1,3,5,6

Comment: Yes thats what I meant if the datatype in the DB is int you do not need quotes.

Answer (score 0):

try with `where_in` Read [where_in](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html)

```
$this->db->where_in('r.location_id', $this->session->userdata('str_user_locations'));
```

where_in produce result like this

```
 $names = array('Frank', 'Todd', 'James');
    $this->db->where_in('username', $names);
 // Produces: WHERE username IN ('Frank', 'Todd', 'James')
```

Answer (score 0):

Codeignitor Active records adds these quotes and I replaced my query with

```
$sql = 'SELECT
            MAX(CASE WHEN rt.machine_name = "new" THEN rt.request_status_count ELSE "0" END) AS "new",
            MAX(CASE WHEN rt.machine_name = "open" THEN rt.request_status_count ELSE "0" END) AS "open",
            MAX(CASE WHEN rt.machine_name = "waiting" THEN rt.request_status_count ELSE "0" END) AS "waiting",
            MAX(CASE WHEN rt.machine_name = "closed" THEN rt.request_status_count ELSE "0" END) AS "closed"
            FROM 
            (SELECT COUNT(r.id) AS request_status_count, rs.name AS status, rs.machine_name AS machine_name
            FROM '. $this->_table . ' r INNER JOIN request_status AS rs ON r.request_status_id = rs.id INNER JOIN organizations AS o ON r.organization_id = o.id '. $where_string .' GROUP BY r.request_status_id) AS rt';

        $query = $this->db->query($sql);  
        return $query->result_array();
```